# Power Query Excel File Missing Data Issue

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm new to Power Query and running into a strange issue that I haven't been able to resolve.

I'm creating a query to to extract data from roughly 300 Excel files.  Each file has one sheet, 115 Columns and around 100 rows.  However, the query is only returning the data from the first two columns and rows and I'm not sure why the query won't return all of the data on the sheet.

Ex:
Header 1 Header 2
Data     Data

I converted one file to a .csv file and the query will return all data from the file.  I've scoured Google and I haven't been able to find anything that seems to relate to this issue.  Is there an excel file limitation that I'm not aware of?

I'm assisting someone that is not technical savvy so I would like to try to avoid VB code and Access if possible.  Also, I can't really provide a file I'm working with because the data contains PHI.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you able to provide a scrubbed version of one of the Excel files? If you can recreate the issue with the scrubbed file, you can share that to help us resolve this issue.

Comment: It's not obvious how you are extracting from 300 Excel files in one Query. Various techniques are around, but it is not built in to PQ.  Can you share your M script? Edit your Query and click the Advanced Editor.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I'll try to get a scrubbed version of the file and copy the M code when I get into the office on Monday.  I messed around with it more today and I realized that all of the data would display in power query if I opened the file and re-saved the file.  I didn't change anything in the file or change the file type.